# mysqlcheck returns Errors

Tags: mysql, myisam, mysqlcheck

I have 4 `MySQL` database VMs, all with the same HD/RAM schemas.
Server version: 5.6.27 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

I ran the `mysqlcheck` command on each Machine:

> $ mysqlcheck -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD --auto-repair --check --all-databases

Btw, only MyISAM tables exist on these machines.
3 of the 4 machines appear good to go.  However, one machine gives me the following response:

```
$ mysqlcheck -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD --auto-repair --check --all-databases
Enter password:
mysql.columns_priv                                 OK
mysql.db                                           OK
mysql.event                                        OK
mysql.func                                         OK
mysql.general_log                                  OK
mysql.help_category                                OK
mysql.help_keyword                                 OK
mysql.help_relation                                OK
mysql.help_topic                                   OK
mysql.innodb_index_stats
Error    : Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.innodb_table_stats
Error    : Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.ndb_binlog_index                             OK
mysql.plugin                                       OK
mysql.proc                                         OK
mysql.procs_priv                                   OK
mysql.proxies_priv                                 OK
mysql.servers                                      OK
mysql.slave_master_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slave_relay_log_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_relay_log_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slave_worker_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_worker_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slow_log                                     OK
mysql.tables_priv                                  OK
mysql.time_zone                                    OK
mysql.time_zone_leap_second                        OK
mysql.time_zone_name                               OK
mysql.time_zone_transition                         OK
mysql.time_zone_transition_type                    OK
mysql.user                                         OK

Repairing tables
mysql.innodb_index_stats
Error    : Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.innodb_table_stats
Error    : Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slave_master_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slave_relay_log_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_relay_log_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slave_worker_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_worker_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
```

This particular MySQL service has no databases yet (minus the typical `mysql`, `information_schema`, `performance_schema`). Considering I cloned each VM from the first one, I didn't expect any real differences.

Is this a unique cosmic-weirdness where I'll need to start fresh?
Or has anyone faced this response from the `mysqlcheck` command before?

Comment: It doesn't sound like your cloning went very well.  Unless somebody has been tinkering, this is unexpected.  I'd start over.

Comment: Check to see if all servers have the same tables in `mysql`.